# How to return ArrayBuffer from $http request in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I sent a `$http.post` request from Angular.js to Node.js in order to get an `ArrayBuffer` as following:

```
$http.post('/api/scholarships/load/uploaded-files', Global.user, {responseType:'arraybuffer'}).success(function(ab){
    console.log(ab); // Return ArrayBuffer {}
});
```

Then, in Node.js, I retrieved uploaded files data and transform a `Buffer` object to `ArrayBuffer` object:

```
exports.loadUploadedFiles = function(req, res) {
    db.UserFile.findAll().success(function(files) {
        var buffer = files[0].dataValues.data; // Get buffer
        var arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(buffer.length); // Start transforming Buffer to ArrayBuffer
        var views = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
        for(var i = 0; i < buffer.length; ++i) {
            views[i] = buffer[i];
        }
        res.type('arraybuffer');
        res.send(arrayBuffer); // Send the ArrayBuffer object back to Angular.js
    }).error(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    });
};
```

When I tried to print the response from above `$http.post`, I always got `ArrayBuffer{}`. What did I do wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to create an ArrayBuffer on the server side. In fact just returning the Buffer in node.js should be fine. ArrayBuffer is a concept on the client/browser side to interpret the data coming from the server as an ArrayBuffer. The reason you are getting "ArrayBuffer{}" is probably because node.js is toString()'ing the ArrayBuffer on res.send() because it doesn't understand the object. So try this

```
exports.loadUploadedFiles = function(req, res) {
    db.UserFile.findAll().success(function(files) {
        var buffer = files[0].dataValues.data; // Get buffer
        res.send(buffer);
    }).error(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    });
};
```

Comment: what i was about to post :) ref: [express.js documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.send); res.send() allows sending a String or Buffer

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I transferred it as Buffer, I got a JavaScript object. Would it be possible to transform this object to ArrayBuffer in Angular.js?

Comment: What type of Javascript object did you get? Also what type of data does the buffer contain (i.e. is it JSON)?

Comment: Actually, this is what I got from returning the buffer object from Node.js: ` �PNG


IHDR�,��$'f!IDATx���i�]I�� ���������s'�d���###r�ʒ*����F�^T�jMCh�h�a0�/��`f0�
��ԭFM��T�=�ʭ""3c�F��}s�I�ӷ�޽fv�|������+y~ "�������}����c���o�0�xP k�0�0i7�0ä�0�0�v�0�0L�
�0ä�0�0�v�0�0L�
�0�0i7�0ä�0�0L�
�0�0i7�0ä�0�0�v�0�0L�
�0ä�0�0�v�0�0L�
�0�0i7�0c)�5����ꢯ#�5�a��v�0�0̵[�z�sU�{�y?���Wu>�}�RG�>���Ϣ
���^s;�{��|�6g���0̵;~���p�߿����±�a&��i��h̢�K%l��o�j���>�2���ٰ��, olw�3,� `...

Comment: It looks like a PNG file. I just did a simple test of your scenario and I got the expected 'ab' as ArrayBuffer. What exactly is the type of 'ab' you are getting?

Comment: I also got ArrayBuffer but it's empty: ArrayBuffer{}

Comment: Could you post a simplified version of your code somewhere that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I got it working by using base64 encoding/decoding :) BTW, Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi  LVarayut I am also facing a similar issue. can u plz post how u fixed your issue. any example code?